# When two Dedekind sums are equal

Tags: nt.number-theory, continued-fractions

The (classical) Dedekind sum $s(h,k)$ is defined as

$$s(h,k)=\sum_{r=1}^{k-1}\frac{r}{k}\bigg(\frac{hr}{k}-\Big[\frac{hr}{k}\Big]-\frac{1}{2}\bigg)$$

for $\gcd(h,k)=1$.

A natural question is, when will we have $s(h_1,k)=s(h_2,k)$?

P.S. Of course a sufficient condition is that $h_1\equiv h_2\pmod k$ or $h_1h_2\equiv 1\pmod k$. Moreover, if $k$ is a prime number it is easy to see that the above is also a necessary condition.

Answer (score 2):

You can find a patial answer in the article [On a criterion for the equality of Dedekind Sums](http://arxiv.org/abs/1304.4716v1) $s(h_1,k)=s_2(h_2,k)\pmod{\mathbb Z}$ iff $(h_1-h_2)(h_1h_2-1)=0\pmod k$. The key tool is a formula for Dedekind sum $s(k,h)$ in terms of continued fraction $h/k=[a_0;a_1,\ldots,a_n].$ In the proof the sum $$\tag{*}\sum_{j=1}^n(-1)^{j-1}a_j$$ vanishes modulo $\mathbb{Z}$. If we want exact equality $s(h_1,k)=s_2(h_2,k)$ then we have to add restrictions on the sums $(*)$ for fractions $h_1/k$ and $h_2/k$.

More precise necessary conditions are given in [Equality of Dedekind sums mod ℤ, 2ℤ and 4ℤ](http://www.worldscientific.com/doi/abs/10.1142/S1793042115500748?src=recsys) (Tsukerman, 2014) and [Equality of Dedekind sums mod 8ℤ](https://math.berkeley.edu/~etsuker/Files/equalityT1.20.15.pdf) (Tsukerman, 2015). Probably it is our best up to date knowledge.

Another good sourse of formulae is the article *Hall, R. R. & Huxley, M. N. Dedekind sums and continued fractions Acta Arith., 1993, 63, 79-90.*

Comment: Thanks but the article you mentioned does not provide an answer to my question.

Comment: Why? It gives a criterion as you asked.

Comment: What's the criterion?

Comment: Sorry, I've missed (mod ℤ). I've corrected my answer.

Comment: it seems that the mod Z criterion is almost trivial, which follows immediately from the well-known reciprocity law.